# Accuracy of analog multimeters

Tags: resistance, multimeter, accuracy

What accuracy should I expect from an analog multimeter that cost 50$ when measuring resistance?

It's measuring 1.5 kilohm correctly, when measuring a 10 ohm resistor it's about 30% off. I tested it against my digital multimeter. Return it as "broken" or is this what I should expect in this price range?

Voltcraft VC-2030
https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/gl/001009621ML03/instrukcja-obslugi-1009621-multimetr-analogowy-voltcraft-vc-2030a-cat-iii-500-v.pdf

Comment: Start by looking up the specs for that specific multimeter. What model is it?

Comment: Why would you buy an analog multimeter?

Comment: It's a Voltcraft Hand-Multimeter analog VC-2030

Comment: @Damien For the coming zombie apocalypse when we run out of batteries

Comment: @AzulShiva you still need a battery on your analog multimeter to measure resistors....

Comment: @Damien True. But if I have any power source I can get around it by measuring voltage differences and calculating the resistance. There's always a way.

Comment: Measuring small resistances without a 4-wire method is bound to provide too high values.

Comment: @AzulShiva, the meter make, model and user manual link belong in your question, not buried in the comments. Can you [edit] them in? Also, you didn't say what measurement range you are using to measure the 10 ohm resistor.

Comment: @AzulShiva:  Short the leads, zero the meter, then measure the 10 ohm resistor again.

Comment: The relative error is inversely "proportional" to deviation (current measured) referred to as full scale. It does not say what is absolute error, full scale (did not see).

Comment: Ok, apart from the Zombie Apocalypse thing, the only advantage nowadays for an analog meter is its ability to measure voltages and currents without using batteries. However this comes at a cost: its internal resistance in voltage range is far lower than the standard 10Mohm of any decent DMMs. Do you really need that feature? Moreover, another BIG disadvantage is it is far less robust: drop it on the ground from any moderate height and its delicate mechanical movement will break or will be damaged (it may be a little off, but that will affect accuracy). ...

Comment: ...  This latter "feature" is also a problem in a Zombie Apocalypse: sooner or later you'll have to run and your tools will be mistreated. Your analog meter won't stand a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem probably isn't the inherent accuracy of the meter.  One of the other answers has covered that - the accuracy should be in the range of a few percent.

The more likely cause for really wrong readings (30 percent off is really messed up) is improper use.

Your meter has two things you need to adjust so that you get accurate readings on the ohms scale:

1. Null adjust the meter movement.
2. Zero adjust the ohms function.

The manual tells you where they are, but doesn't go into enough detail about them.

[image: Meter]

Number 3 is the meter movement null adjustment.

Unplug the leads, and adjust the null adjust so that the needle is on the 0 mark for volts and current (left side of the scale.)

Now connect the leads and switch to ohms mode.

Short the leads together and adjust number 6 so that the needle is on 0 ohms (right side of the scale.)

Now measure your 10 ohm resistor.  The result should be much better.

---

Number 6 appears to be the red ring around the function selector knob.

[image]

The manual shows it in gray, so it is hard to see.  The photo is a (little) bit clearer.  You can see that the red ring is separate from the knob and the markings around it.

---

Remember to use the mirror.

Move your head back and forth until the needle covers its own reflection in the mirrored part of the scale.  This makes sure that you are correctly reading the value under the needle rather than off to one side.

Comment: You've got it. I couldn't see where the zero ohm adjustment was. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Transistor I'd also have a hard time to see things on that analog meter image. [This TP7040 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42W3d.jpg) makes it a lot easier to see both. (The photo is from a Reddit question I found.)

Comment: I think you're still missing it, @jonk. Between the pointer knob and the yellow scale there is a knurled red ring. That's the knob for the trim pot! It's nice but the OP doesn't seem to have realised that it's there.

Comment: @Transistor Oh. I see. That's clear now that you point it out. Though, frankly, I wouldn't normally go looking for it there. It's not convenient. The one that is on the TP7040 is clearly marked (there is an arrow on the bezel pointing downward to it) and it sticks up and is easy to grasp and adjust. One might suspect that the main difference between the two would the fine angular adjustments. But that's not a problem for the TP7040 as the knob doesn't have rotation limits and it is easy to rotate and makes very fine adjustments easy.

Comment: @jonk:  I wouldn't normally look for one there either.  I looked at the manual, compared it with the photos, and thought about it off and on all afternoon before deciding that the ohm zero adjust has to be the red ring.  It looks very inconvenient and easy to accidentally bump.

Comment: @JRE I bought four of the TP7040's, a while back when they were about $16 each. Good investment, hindsight 20/20. These are 50uA meter movements (decent, not the best, but quite decent) and they just work pretty well. They are NOT well-protected. If you abuse them they will cease to work, very quickly. But at the price? I couldn't find anything like them. They include a mirror for reducing parallax error and come with more than would be expected for so little money. I do love my Tektronix DMM916 and I use it a lot, too. But these TP7040's are what I can afford to lose and are otherwise good.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: @AzulShiva:  Did you get the meter to work correctly?

Comment: @JRE Yes! And the first zombie is already running over the hill outside my window. Great timing!

Answer (score 0):

The quoted accuracy is 4%, but it doesn't say where on the scale that is. On most ranges, that would be at full scale deflection. But that doesn't make sense for ohms.

It looks like 10 ohms is at the far right of the scale, and towards the lower limit of what the meter can measure.

Try shorting the test leads together, and see what the meter reads. Subtract that from any future readings.

Comment: Generally, the "absolute accuracy" is quoted at "full scale". Remember that the "resistor scale" is not really a "scale", but it is "graduated" with the "measured" current. So, when "ohm" increases (pointer decreases), relative (and absolute) accuracy increases also (inversely proportional to deflexion).

Comment: One can see that the quoted accuracy on the "Ohm scale" is the same that on the "DC current" scale ... which is logical, because "DC current" is measured and "translated" (inverse function) to Ohm.

Comment: So, error on "10 Ohm" measurement is roughly ... ~ 4% * 250 / 220 = ~ 4.6 %. With "50 Ohm", it is ~ 8% ...